# Codeigniter Do I need to check if a variable is set in view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Should I be checking for if a variable is set in the view file ? I mean we are controlling what data is being sent to the view, so ideally it shouldn't be necessary.

And if we check a variable and find that it's not set then what should we do ? Redirect to 404 ? Then again redirecting from view doesn't seem right.

What are the possibilities of a view being loaded without a particular variable ?

I am working in codeigniter.

Comment: you can check if the variable is set in controller itself, in not you can redirect to 404 in controller only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic belongs to `controllers`. You are passing data also from controllers to views.

The best way is to check in your controller, and if it's not exists, do the redirect then.

Views are just visual representation of your data, no logic belongs to there.

Comment: I totally forgot 'Logic belongs to controllers' lol... Thanks for short and precise reply.